# Is it possible to remove the lock of consoles in Solaris?

Tags: console, opensolaris, solaris-11

I installed Solaris 11 with just consoles. Just like with Linux, you can switch between consoles using the Alt-F1 to Alt-F6 key combos. Great. Only, each time you do so, it asks you for your password.

Is there a way to remove the lock on consoles so I don't have to re-enter my password 10 times a minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this should do it, if run as root or with appropriate privileges:

```
svccfg -s vtdaemon setprop options/secure=false
svcadm refresh vtdaemon
svcadm restart vtdaemon
```

Comment: Ah! Pretty good! You also need to refresh and restart as shown on this page: https://blogs.oracle.com/DanX/entry/solaris_virtual_consoles -- you may want to update your answer with those additional two commands. Also you have to be root it looks like.

Comment: Oops, I forgot about those - if you don't run them it won't take effect until after you reboot.  Answer updated to include that as you suggested.